# I am trying to make a discord bot that is able to log messages, but my code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
client.on(`message`, message => {
    if (!message.guild) return; 
    if(!message.content.includes('*quota')) return;
    if (message.guild) {
        const msgLog = `[MESSAGE] [${message.guild.name}] [#${message.channel.name}] ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${message.content}\n`
        client.channels.get('1146474290624081950').send(msgLog); 
        return;
    }
})
```

I have the code there, I want it to only log messages that contain '*quota'
I tried it like how the code was now but it didn't log anything. I don't have any solutions to this
and I couldn't find anything about how to fix it so I hope someone can help me here!

Comment: Javascript cannot compile images as code.

Comment: Questions should include code any in question, posted as formatted text, as opposed to links to images of formatted text 

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** `client.on('message')` is invalid, use `client.on('messageCreate')` instead.
So in your case,

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (messsage) => {
    if (!message.guild) return; 
    if(!message.content.includes('*quota')) return;
    if (message.guild) {
        const msgLog = `[MESSAGE] [${message.guild.name}] [#${message.channel.name}] ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${message.content}\n`
        client.channels.get('1146474290624081950').send(msgLog); 
        return;
    }
})
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you have given your bot the correct intents.